# Record RAM usage during runtime of a Java Application

Tags: java, ram, logging

I want to evaluate how some code transformations change the RAM usage of a Java Application. Is there a possibility to log the average RAM usage or the highest peak of the RAM usage in the shell during the runtime of a specified Java Application?

Thank you in advance for all answers!

Comment: Use a proper memory profiler. Valgrind might be the best option, or if you use Eclipse, try http://www.eclipse.org/mat/.

Comment: You want total memory usage or just how much that specific app is utilizing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to log largest total memory usage for specific process, here's a script that can do that for you:

```
$ cat watch-mem-usage.sh                                                                       
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
PREVIOUS=0

while  true ;do 
sleep 1
    DATA=$(ps -p $(pgrep firefox) -o vsize= )

    if [ $PREVIOUS -lt $DATA ]; then 
        echo $DATA > logfile.txt
    fi

    PREVIOUS=$(printf "%d" $DATA)
done
```